# make child bones ignore parent transformations

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, parent

(please excuse the bad explanation I'm in a hurry to type this) I'm trying to have child bones not be affected by parent bone so it would be easier to make specific animations like walking or pushing something. I will attach textures later if needed, but if more info is needed besides that, let me know asap. (in the final picture, the red dotted line shows parent relations and the bones pointed to with blue text shows the child's bones)
[image]
[image][image]

Comment: To clarify, are you the one making the rig and you ask how to make a rig that allows that, or is this a rig someone else made and you ask how to use it?

Comment: The rig is mine but the model was ripped from a Nintendo game. Nintendo allows use of all copyright assets as long as no revenue is made. I deleted the original rig (because it sucked) and made this one

Comment: Ok give me some time to write an answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an IK, it should be relatively easy: just set the IK controller's parent to the root instead of the hips.

BUT, ideally, you want to be able to use both depending on the situation. In which case, you also want to add [**Child of**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/relationship/child_of.html) constraints to your IK controllers, pointing to your hips controller. Then you can turn that constraint on and off via its weight:

[image: demo constraints]

If you want even more control, you can even use separate [**Copy Location**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/transform/copy_rotation.html) and [**Copy Rotation**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/transform/copy_rotation.html) instead of **`Child Of`**, so that you can define what influences your location and rotation individually.

Comment: to anyone else looking for the answer to this, once you apply the child of constraint, if the leg seems to move twice as much then check if the bone that was given the constraint is parented to the bone youre rotating. if so, press `Alt` + `p` and click clear parent.

and if the target bone for the IK moves along with any new transforms, give the target bone the child of constraint as well and mimic any edits you make of the foots constraint to the target bones constraint. then clear the parent of the target bone and parent the target bone to the foot

Comment: Or just do as I described? :o